# Перемещение файлов с разными именами из папки в папку и на удалённый сервер

Tags: python, linux, scp

Привет! Мне нужно переместить файлы с разными именами (общий вид названия: **photo-[дата]-[время].jpg**), с помощью python скрипта, из папки *А* в папку *Б*. Для копирования пробовал использовать *copyfile*, но переместить не удалось, ибо скрипт ссылался на отсутствие файла (прописывал имя как:  **/home/results/*.jpg**).

После перемещения нескольких файлов в папку *Б*, их нужно закинуть на удалённый сервер. Для этой операции нужно использовать SCP, или есть более удобные инструменты?

Все способы, которые использовались:

[image: Тут ещё немного идей по предмету вопроса]

Comment: Как я понимаю, вопрос с копированием в локальный каталог решён? код с виду рабочий... Для копирования на удалённый сервер, SCP — самый простой и универсальный способ... Как альтернативу можно ещё rsync поверх какого-либо тунеля (того же ssh) пустить — проще/эффективней будет в случае необходимости инкрементальных копий, но несколько сложней в реализации. ЗЫ: на будущее, код в вопросы лучше вставлять текстом, а не скринами.

Comment: https://github.com/smartfile/python-librsync

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: вопрос об scp отдельно задайте. Он не имеет отношения к копированию между папками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы переместить `photo-*.jpg` файлы из папки `A` в папку `B`,
 аналог
`mv -t B A/photo-*.jpg` команды:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path('A').glob('photo-*.jpg'):
    path.replace(Path('B') / path.name)
```